# 502 Bad gateway error for qradar v 7.3.0 patch 3 application

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, werkzeug

We are receiving below error while loading dashboards with multiple panels. Only few get are loading OK. and rest are failed with below error.

```
2017/09/13 07:42:06 [error] 104#0: *9058 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.1.65, server: , request: "GET /qapp-1252/flask/widgets/Network_Traffic?start=2017-09-06%2013%3A07&end=2017-09-13%2013%3A07&free_search= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.1.65:9825/widgets/Network_Traffic?start=2017-09-06%2013%3A07&end=2017-09-13%2013%3A07&free_search=", host: "10.0.1.65:1443", referrer: "https://10.0.1.65/console/plugins/1252/app_proxy/Network_Protection_Glance"
```

we tried modifying following parameters in nginx but did not fix the issue.

```
worker_processes        4;
events {
        worker_connections      1024;
}
http {
        include         mime.types;
        default_type    application/octet-stream;
        sendfile                on;
        keepalive_timeout       165;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
}
```

below is proxy_pass config.

```
location /qapp-1257/flask/ {
                client_max_body_size    0;
                proxy_connect_timeout   600;
                proxy_send_timeout      600;
                proxy_read_timeout      600;
                send_timeout            600;
                auth_basic on;
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/nginx-auth.conf;
          proxy_pass http://qapp-1257_flask_upstream/;
        }
```

Yes, we are reciving below error on flask app log.

```
169.254.3.1 - - [14/Sep/2017 11:08:19] "GET /widgets/endpoint_investigation_malfile?start=2017-09-07%2011%3A08&end=2017-09-14%2011%3A08&free_search= HTTP/1.0" 200 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 200, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: where is the main config which does proxy_pass?

Comment: yes. updated main confing

Comment: What do you see in your flask logs, i think there may be some exception

Comment: Yes, we are receiving error on flask app log. updated error

Comment: See if these links help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145357/python-error-socket-error-errno-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-when-s and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340893/oserror-errno-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-what-causes-this

Comment: can this error be due to the configuration of timeout ?  please suggest. looks like when it tries to read or write we get this IOError.

Comment: Lower the timeouts, high timeouts are not always effective