# Python3 non-blocking recv

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I trying to do a simple server. The server has to load data while client provides it. I want to use non-blocking '*recv*' command, but whatever I do it still blocks. My code is above.

```
import socket
import fcntl
import os

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.bind(("localhost", 8888))
server_socket.listen()
client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()

#fcntl.fcntl(client_socket, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK) #mark1
client_socket.setblocking(False)                          #mark2
#client_socket.settimeout(0.0)                            #mark3

while True:
    data = client_socket.recv(10)
    if len(data) != 0:
        print(data.decode("UTF8"))
    else:
        break

print("Exit")
```

I tried to use lines '*#mark1*', '*#mark2*', '*#mark3*'. These lines seem to be pretty good for me, but my program is still stuck on the second iteration with `data = client_socket.recv(10)` line.

Why do `client_socket.setblocking(False)` and others not affect?

Comment: your code is setting timeout on blocking methods, you should get a timeout exception. By `non-blocking recv command`, do you mean that you want multiple clients talking to the server simultaneously?

Comment: I should get timeout exception, I agree. But the method 'recv' is stuck, and I can't understand why does it occur. Can you help me with this problem? Because it isn't clear tor me.

Comment: I have hear I can use 'select'  or 'epool' for processing few users. But, I want to understand this code, and why the code works as works. It works differently with documentation.

Comment: what I said was incorrect, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145357/python-error-socket-error-errno-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-when-s)